# Can't login on IIS website hosted on Azure VM with Windows Authentication

Tags: azure, iis, windows-authentication, azure-vm

I've deployed a IIS website on an Azure VM. It uses Windows authentication for access. We setup Azure AD Domain Services so we can use oldschool Kerberos for authentiation and this all works perfect... as long as I'm in the VM.

As soon as I try to connect to the website from outside using a public IP it fails to authenticate. When I look in IIS logs I see 401 errors but it doesn't log the username I tried, so it looks like somehow the credentials I fill in are not passed to IIS i.e. the Azure VM. What am I missing in this configuration?

Comment: Windows authentication is only feasible for internal networking, so switch to other authentication methods (forms authentication commonly).

Comment: To be clear, the requirement is that the browser must have line of sight to a domain controller to do Kerberos, otherwise it'll fall back to NTLM where the server forwards to the DC. A fiddler and network trace from the client would go a long way in figuring out what its actually doing and what step is failing.

Comment: I just want to connect to website running on a VM with IIS and use AD credentials. It seems that it just doesnt act the same way when running it in Azure with AD Domain services.